# Рендер результата работы цикла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, в `input` пользователь вводит вопросы, по событие `keyup` каждый раз запускается функция которая сравнивает совпадения в вводе пользователя и в объекте (ранее заготовленном). Объект перебирается циклом `for(key in data)` и если `data[key].answer == вводу пользователя(хотя бы частично)` то я вывожу поле из объекта в `HTML`.

Проблема в том что т.к. цикл запускается много раз, много раз находятся совпадения (одни и те же) и при рендере получается, что я вывожу вместо одного совпавшего ответа (например) `Привет`, штук 30...
Как правильно отследить этот момент и рендерить только 1 совпавшее поле объекта в `HTML`? рендерится всё сюда

```
$('div.Answers').append('<p>' + data[key].answer + '</p>')
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('div.Answers p.' + key).length == 0) {
  $('div.Answers').append('<p class="' + key + '"></p>');
}
$('div.Answers p.' + key).text(data[key].answer);
```

а лучше

```
if ($('div.Answers p.[data-key="' + key + '"]').length == 0) {
  $('div.Answers').append('<p data-key="' + key + '"></p>');
}
$('div.Answers p.[data-key="' + key + '"]').text(data[key].answer);
```

Comment: Интересный вариант с классом) ничего страшного, что класс будет на кириллице?)

Comment: @СергейКозин надо, чтобы там не было пробелов, точек и т.п. - того, что может сломать селектор

Comment: @СергейКозин Можно вместо класса использовать aтрибут `data-key` .

Comment: Спасибо, интересный для меня вариант) а главное рабочий)